# How do I format my api call to post in google spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-headers

I've set up below API call to seatgeek but I'm having an issue structuring the response. I'd like to take the four headers within the "stats" attribute, among a few others, and write it to my spreadsheet. I can't figure out how to pull the data properly and I believe it's because I don't know how to set up syntax to establish headers. Below is the seatgeek documentation ([or you can find here - about 1/3 down the page under Events](https://platform.seatgeek.com/)):

```
{
 "stats": {
  "listing_count": 161,
  "average_price": 97,
  "lowest_price": 62,
  "highest_price": 296
},
```

To complete my call, I've set up my code as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
 var url = 'A1';
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 var json = response.getContentText();
 var data = JSON.parse(json);
 Logger.log(data);
}
```

I followed along a youtube video so this works but it's not structured properly. If I check the logger, this returns what I would guess is xml format (below)? It's a string of data and if I read through it, sure enough, the "stats" I'm looking for are buried in the middle.

```
19-11-21 16:08:32:853 CST] {meta={per_page=1, took=3, total=1, page=1, 
geolocation=null}, in_hand={}, events=[{venue={display_location=Denver, 
CO, country=US, access_method={method=NONE, created_at=2015-11- 
04T17:30:28Z, employee_only=false}, address=1000 Chopper Circle,  
city=Denver, timezone=America/Denver, 
url=https://seatgeek.com/venues/pepsi-center/tickets, capacity=21000, 
extended_address=Denver, CO 80204, score=0.7527942, 
num_upcoming_events=106, name_v2=Pepsi Center, metro_code=751, 
popularity=0, name=Pepsi Center, links=[], location={lon=-105.008, 
lat=39.7487}, id=187, state=CO, postal_code=80204, slug=pepsi-center, 
has_upcoming_events=true}, access_method={method=NONE, created_at=2015- 
11-04T17:30:28Z, employee_only=false}, conditional=false, 
date_tbd=false, description=, created_at=2019-08-12T20:15:53, 
title=Portland Trail Blazers at Denver Nuggets, type=nba, score=0.687, 
short_title=Trail Blazers at Nuggets, visible_until_utc=2019-12- 
13T07:30:00, stats={lowest_sg_base_price_good_deals=13, 
visible_listing_count=718, lowest_price_good_deals=20, 
average_price=120, lowest_price=20, highest_price=1780, 
lowest_sg_base_price=13, listing_count=885, dq_bucket_counts=[86, 283, 
162, 66, 72, 106, 72, 5], median_price=80}, popularity=0.758, links=[], 
id=4960016, performers=[{image=https://seatgeek.com/images/performers- 
landscape/denver-nuggets-ea3cb6/2103/huge.jpg, images= . 
{huge=https://seatgeek.com/images/performers-landscape/denver-nuggets- 
ea3cb6/2103/huge.jpg}, 
image_license=https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/, type=nba, 
colors={all=[#0E2240, #FEC524, #0E2240], iconic=#0E2240, primary= . 
[#0E2240, #FEC524]}, divisions=[{display_type=Conference,  
taxonomy_id=1030100, short_name=null, display_name=Western Conference, 
slug=null, division_level=1}, {display_type=Division,  
taxonomy_id=1030100, short_name=Northwest, display_name=Western - 
Northwest, slug=western-northwest, division_level=2}], 
url=https://seatgeek.com/denver-nuggets-tickets, score=0.7, 
num_upcoming_events=69, stats={event_count=69}, taxonomies= . 
[{parent_id=null, name=sports, document_source={source_type=ELASTIC, 
generation_type=FULL}, id=1000000}, {parent_id=1000000, 
name=basketball, document_source={source_type=ELASTIC, 
generation_type=FULL}, id=1030000}, {parent_id=1030000, name=nba, 
document_source={source_type=ELASTIC, generation_type=FULL}, 
id=1030100}], popularity=0, 
image_attribution=https://www.flickr.com/photos/34247743@N07/ 
5342565327/in/photolist-9973xi-996Uxp-996Qwr-9971mx-pW93vv-9ddXGD- 
9dcgRk-9dh49b-eXUzb7-eXUyqJ-eXUyJU-gAGfkV-9ddVN4-efsxLC-efmNi4-nLwpvg- 
efmNqB-bGHTnP-btP6DQ-btP2NY-btP36U-bGHQX2-bGHSEK-btP3Wm-bGHRQc-bGHSa2- 
9dfrVw-7qjEsp-6t2y82-7qoAD9-7qozqW-7qoyRj-7qoyg3-6QTVX7-jrx2ht-a8hFoL- 
9dgYYm-rY1RES-s1iU4H-rJi58H-r4X6SX-s1FLi4-m1dYBZ-nMXgaJ-rZKUfA-rFyrmk- 
rZTsUc-rZKTmb-9myz8B-rJ3c8q, name=Denver Nuggets, location= . 
{lon=-105.008, lat=39.7487}, short_name=Nuggets, id=2103, 
home_team=true, home_venue_id=187, slug=denver-nuggets, primary=true, 
has_upcoming_events=true}, 
{image=https://seatgeek.com/images/performers-landscape/portland-trail- 
blazers-d0de88/2106/huge.jpg, images= . 
{huge=https://seatgeek.com/images/performers-landscape/portland-trail- 
blazers-d0de88/2106/huge.jpg}, 
image_license=https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en, 
type=nba, colors={all=[#191919, #D01631, #191919], iconic=#D01631, 
primary=[#191919, #D01631]}, divisions=[{display_type=Conference, 
taxonomy_id=1030100, short_name=null, display_name=Western Conference, 
slug=null, division_level=1}, {display_type=Division, 
taxonomy_id=1030100, short_name=Northwest, display_name=Western - 
Northwest, slug=western-northwest, division_level=2}], 
url=https://seatgeek.com/portland-trail-blazers-tickets, 
away_team=true, score=0.71, num_upcoming_events=67, stats= . 
{event_count=67}, taxonomies=[{parent_id=null, name=sports, 
document_source={source_type=ELASTIC, generation_type=FULL}, 
id=1000000}, {parent_id=1000000, name=basketball, document_source= . 
{source_type=ELASTIC, generation_type=FULL}, id=1030000}, 
{parent_id=1030000, name=nba, document_source={source_type=ELASTIC, 
generation_type=FULL}, id=1030100}], popularity=0, 
datetime_utc=2019-12-13T03:30:00, enddatetime_utc=null, 
url=https://seatgeek.com/trail-blazers-at-nuggets-tickets/12-12-2019- 
denver-colorado-pepsi-center/nba/4960016, event_promotion=null, 
announce_date=2019-08-12T00:00:00, datetime_tbd=false, taxonomies= . 
[{parent_id=null, name=sports, id=1000000}, {parent_id=1000000, 
name=basketball, id=1030000}, {parent_id=1030000, name=nba, 
id=1030100}], datetime_local=2019-12-12T20:30:00, time_tbd=false, 
announcements={}, status=normal}]}
```

The youtube video adjusts their last line to specify the attribute from which they'd like to pull data. If I follow suit and add "stats" in my last line (like below), I receive an "undefined" error.

```
Logger.log(data.stats)
```

Even still, I don't want to just "log" the call, I want it on my spreadsheet. How do I call the data with the proper headers and set it up to be pasted in my sheet?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);` is `{"stats": {"listing_count": 161,"average_price": 97,"lowest_price": 62,"highest_price": 296},`? If it's so, `Logger.log(data.stats)` doesn't return `undefined`. I think that in order to correctly confirm your issue, can you provide a sample value of `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: No, it's not "stats". I took that code from the seatgeek api documentation as a json example of how the data would be returned ([about a third of the way down](https://platform.seatgeek.com/) under Events).

I tried to run only lines 1-3 up through 'response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);' and don't get anything back.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, can you provide a sample value of `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: can you provide the output of `Logger.log(data)`?

Comment: @ZektorH logger output (gets cut of because of character limit):

'[19-11-21 07:56:13:240 CST] {meta={per_page=1, took=3, total=1, page=1, geolocation=null}, in_hand={}, events=[{venue={display_location=Denver, CO, country=US, access_method={method=NONE, created_at=2015-11-04T17:30:28Z, employee_only=false}, address=1000 Chopper Circle, city=Denver, timezone=America/Denver, url=https://seatgeek.com/venues/pepsi-center/tickets, capacity=21000, extended_address=Denver, CO 80204, score=0.7527942, num_upcoming_events=106, name_v2=Pepsi Center, metro_code=751, popularity=0, name=Pepsi Center,

Comment: @Tanaike np, thanks for the help.. response of var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);... doesn't return anything. It runs fine but I don't see data anywhere (I'm running native in the scripting window in sheets).

Comment: Could you update your question to have the information provided here and also the link you are calling on A1?

Comment: @ZektorH you bet. Done.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `doesn't return anything`, `response` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);` is `null`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please familiarize yourself with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

## Problem

What you refereed to as "XML Object" is in fact the "String" version of a JSON Object.

You are merely [accessing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) on your object when they (*the properties*) don't exist.

To prove my point, here is an experiment:

The code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var j = {
    "meta": [],
    "in_hand": [],
    "events": [
      {"a":"1"},
      {"a":"2"}
    ]
  };
  
  Logger.log(j); //Here is the "XML" version of the object, as you said.
  Logger.log(j.doesnotexist); //This will say undefined, meaning this property does not exist.
}
```

Outputs: `{meta=[], in_hand=[], events=[{a=1}, {a=2}]}`

## Solution

With that in mind, here is how to solve your problem. The Object that you API returns is in the following format:

```
{
  meta,
  in_hand,
  events = [{
    venue = {},
    access_method = {},
    conditional=false,
    date_tbd=false,
    // Other properties here, then, finally:
    stats = {},
    // Then more properties here.
  }]
}
```

Assuming your `data` variable holds the result of `JSON.parse`, your `stats` variable should be:

```
var stats = data.events[0].stats;
```

Also, if you were returning multiple events, you could have an array of Stats like this:

```
var stats = [];
for (var i = 0; i<data.events.length; i++) {
  stats.push(data.events[i].stats);
}
```

Hope I was able to clarify and guide you to a solution. Take care.

Comment: This worked - I now have the stats in my logger. Thanks @ZektorH !

Comment: Please remember to accept answers that help you so Stack Overflow is able to serve this knowledge to other users with similar problems.